Participants: Contact Summary Events
I would like the DEFAULT order of the event listing on the Events tab of a contact summary page to be ordered by Register Date (newest first). Editing Contact Summary Events Tab allows me to toggle sortable header on and off, but any help in changing the default order of the table would be most appreciated. (CiviCRM 5.72.1)

If you have AdminUI (Preview) and FormBuilder installed, you can change the Searchkit search to default order by date
https://file.io/dWhEulOW5QjF
